# Исключение в конструкторе класса c#

Tags: c#, .net, исключения

Когда писал на с++ все говорили, что выбрасывать исключение в конструкторе это плохая идея, так как может создать утечку памяти, а что вы можете сказать о исключениях выбрасываемых в конструкторах классов написанных на c#?

```
public FilePathExplorer(string _path)
{
    if (_path == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Argument _path can not be null.");
    this._path = _path;
}
```

Comment: а есть принципиальная разница?

Comment: @Grundy наличие GC не является принципиальной разницей?

Comment: А какая связь GC с исключениями в конструкторе?

Comment: @Grundy разница в том что у с++ ни в конструкторе ни где бы то нибыло его нету, а в с# есть.

Comment: Так а связь-то какая?

Comment: @Grundy связь в том, что возможно, GC как то решает проблемы, возникающие при использовании исключений которые были в с++

Comment: А какая может быть утечка памяти? Ссылка на объект в переменную фактически не будет записана, поэтому даже если что-то создастся — сборщик мусора это подберет.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, спасибо я приблизительно так и думал, но хотелось бы уверенности и советов от комьюнити c#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Выбрасывание исключений из конструктора - это как раз таки единственно правильный способ сообщить вызывающему коду, что объект не может быть создан. Это правило работает как в C++, так и C#.

Попытки же использовать какой-то флаг типа `bool initialized` не приводят ни к чему хорошему. Этот флаг можно элементарно забыть проверить и пытаться пользоваться объектом, который был как бы создан (конструктор отработал), но фактически (по логике программы) не инициализирован должным образом.

Comment: [немножко ссылочек :)](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#ctors-can-throw)